# Idris: Writing an initial segments function for vectors with length as a Fin rather than a Nat

Tags: idris

I'm trying to write an initial segments function for vectors, which stores the length of the vector as a Fin rather than a Nat, as follows:

```
vectorsInits : Vect n t -> Vect n (p ** Vect (finToNat p) t)
vectorsInits Nil = Nil
vectorsInits (x::xs) = ((FS FZ) ** (x::Nil)) :: map (\(p ** ys) => ((FS p) ** x::ys)) (vectorsInits xs)
```

This definitions doesn't work however as i get the following type error:

```
When checking right hand side of vectorsInits with expected type

    Vect (S len) (p : Fin n ** Vect (finToNat p) t)

When checking argument pf to constructor Builtins.MkDPair:

    Type mismatch between

            Vect 1 t (Type of [x])

    and

            Vect (finToNat (FS FZ)) t (Expected type)

    Specifically:

            Type mismatch between

                    1

            and

                    finToNat (FS FZ)
```

But the definition of finToNat is clear that finToNat (FS FZ) would equal 1,. even if I write the following function to try and get idris to realise they're equal, I get an error:

```
intproof : Vect 1 t -> Vect (finToNat (FS FZ)) t 
intproof x = x
...
vectorsInits (x::xs) = ((FS FZ) ** intproof (x::Nil)) :: map (\(p ** ys) => ((FS p) ** x::ys)) (vectorsInits xs)
```

gives me the error:

```
When checking right hand side of vectorsInits with expected type
        Vect (S len) (p : Fin n ** Vect (finToNat p) t)
When checking argument pf to constructor Builtins.MkDPair:
    Type mismatch between
            Vect (finToNat (FS FZ)) t (Type of intproof [x])
    and
            (\p => Vect (finToNat p) t) (FS FZ) (Expected type)
    Specifically:
            Type mismatch between
                    1
            and
                    finToNat (FS FZ)
```

even writing:

```
intproof : Vect 1 t -> (\p => Vect (finToNat p) t) (FS FZ)
intproof x = x
```

gets an identical error as above

I've got %default total and I'm importing Data.Vect at the beginning of my file.

Is there any way to force Idris to recognise that finToNat (FS FZ) is equal to 1 (that is, S Z))?

Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to write a function with the type you've provided, because it would lead to a contradiction -- see [this proof](https://gist.github.com/anton-trunov/857a5de6d5389b0efe98314d2e108a57).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an issue:

```
vectorsInits : Vect n t -> Vect n (p ** Vect (finToNat p) t)
```

What is the type of `p`? You haven't given it, and it actually ends up being

```
vectorsInits : Vect n t -> Vect n (p : Fin m ** Vect (finToNat p) t)
```

That is, the type of the `Fin`s running beside your data, is totally unrelated to the input. That's not right. It should (at least) be

```
vectorsInits : Vect n t -> Vect n (p : Fin n ** Vect (finToNat p) t)
```

However, that's not quite right either. What should happen is that the `Fin`s count up from `FZ` to `last` as you go down the output, but your current implementation does not do that. If you change it to do so, you'll notice that each output vector ends up having a length one greater than the index:

```
vectorsInits : Vect n t -> Vect n (p : Fin n ** Vect (S (finToNat p)) t)
vectorsInits [] = []
vectorsInits (x :: xs) = (FZ ** [x]) :: map (\(idx ** ixs) => (FS idx ** x :: ixs)) (vectorsInits xs)
```

Or, you can affix a `[]` to the start of the output (after all, `[]` is a prefix of every list), and thus get a version which obeys the identity `index n (vectorInits xs) = take n xs` (some mangling omitted):

```
vectorsInits : Vect n t -> Vect (S n) (p : Fin (S n) ** Vect (finToNat p) t) 
vectorsInits [] = [(FZ ** [])] 
vectorsInits (x :: xs) = (FZ ** []) :: map (\(idx ** ixs) => (FS idx ** x :: ixs)) (vectorsInits xs)
```